# Missing sub-menu

Tags: theming, routes, 8

I have configured my main menu to have several sub-menu entries but unfortunately they don't show up. The menu is rendered using a custom template (menu--main.html.twig) but I don't think that this is the problem because when I print the menu using kint item.below is an empty array.

Unfortunately I have no idea how to find out what the problem could be. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the block settings there are settings for menu levels, check those first, also you may need to expand items in the actual menu configuration, e.g./admin/structure/menu/manage/main edit each item and set to expanded.

Answer (score 2):

Like Jeff stated, make sure your parent menu item is configured to "Show as expanded"

[image]